# how to align items inside textformfields?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, textfield, textformfield

How do I properly align the prefix icon, the hintText, the actual value that the user has typed in and the suffix icon? I am using textformfield for this one.

```
Widget yourNameWidget(yourNameCtrlr) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
    child: TextFormField(
      style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontSize: 12),
      controller: yourNameCtrlr,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
        isDense: true,
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
        ),
// this does not align with the prefix and the hint text
        suffix: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            yourNameCtrlr.clear();
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.clear,
            size: 16,
          ),
        ),
        hintText: 'Your Name',
        fillColor: const Color(0xFFFEFEFE),
        filled: true,
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty || !RegExp(r'^[a-z A-Z]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
          return "Please enter a valid name.";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
    ),
  );
}
```

I want the three of it (prefix,hint text, suffix) should be aligned.
Here is the image for the preview of the textformfield

https://prnt.sc/BxYxnZx1G5od

Comment: you have to use image assets for suffixes and prefix please check my solution

Comment: Also use content padding